# unknown attribute: admin_id with nested views and has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Basically my issue is that when trying to use nested views in my rails application I need to store both general users and admins for a page.  Both contain the same information I just need to know who is whom.  I have a Team model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :auth_token, :team_name, :template
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users
  has_many :admins, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'admin_id'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :admins
end
```

And my schema for the Teams table contains an admin_id field. I do not understand why I am getting this error.  I have tried quite a bit of googling and searching through forums and despite finding some similar issues I couldn't find all of the same combinations of issues that I was having.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'digest/sha1'
    attr_accessor :pre_pass
    belongs_to :team
    attr_accessible :name, :player
    attr_protected :password
    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :pre_pass, :presence => true
    before_save :encrypt_pass
    after_save :clear_pre_pass
end
```

Teams/new View

```
<%= form_for(@team) do |f| %>
  <% if @team.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@team.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this team from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @team.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :team_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :team_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :template %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :template %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :auth_token %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :auth_token %>
</div>
    <p>
        <%= f.fields_for :admins do |builder| %>
            <%= render "admin_fields", :f => builder %>
        <% end %>
    </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in TeamsController#new

```
unknown attribute: user_id
```

app/controllers/teams_controller.rb:28:in `new'

TeamController#new

```
def new
    @team = Team.new
    @team.admins.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @team }
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the User Model and the view where you want to add nested form?

Comment: does _users_ table contain "admin_id" column?

Comment: @shweta The users table does not contain an admin_id column as I want the admin_id to simply be another user_id with a different name.

Comment: Show us the error, please.

Comment: @shweta I should note that I get the same error if I use 'user_id' instead of 'admin_id'

Comment: Does the player column define the role? I mean admin/member?

Comment: how do you differentiate between admin and other users in _users_ table?

Comment: Can a user be a member of only one team?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can not set :foreign_key option to column that does not exist in the table.
your *users* table does not have "user_id" or "admin_id" columns.

In any case, Rails will not create foreign key columns for you. You need to explicitly define them as part of your migrations.

see [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-foreign_key)

Comment: Thanks.  I had my database concept for this relation backwards. I can work with this no problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @Shweta suggested,

> you can not set :foreign_key option to column that does not exist in the table. your users table does not have "user_id" or "admin_id" columns.
>
> In any case, Rails will not create foreign key columns for you. You need to explicitly define them as part of your migrations.

So, if user can belong to only one team then you should use have `team_id` in your users table. If you have it then you can define a scope in User model as:

```
scope :admins, where(:player => 'Admin') # I am assuming player is keeping Admin/Member.
```

And in your Team model replace

```
has_many :admins, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'admin_id'
accepts_nested_attributes_for :admins
```

with

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

In your Teams#new action, replace

```
@team.admins.build
```

with

```
@team.users.build
```

And finally, in your view, if you are using fields_for

```
<%= f.fields_for :users do |admin| %>
  <%= admin.hidden_field :player, :value => 'Admin' %>
  <% add other user fields %>
<% end %>
```

Now you can get the admins of a team by `@team.users.admins`

Answer (score 0):

Try `user_id` as foreign_key. I think that ActiveRecord is not so smart to understand that you want to call `user_id` while calling `admin_id`.